# Opening an Eclipse project already in my workspace

Tags: eclipse, project

If I have an Eclipse project already in my workspace (say downloaded from version control), how can I open it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It is kind of funny/misleading, but Eclipse doesn't provide an "Open" command. You need to use "File"->"Import"->"General"->"Import Existing Project" to be able to use your existing project.

you have to uncheck `'Copy projects into workspace'` if the project is already in the workspace

Comment: you have to uncheck 'Copy projects into workspace' if the project is already in the workspace

Comment: I am using eclipse on mac, it is not allowing me to import an existing project in workspace.

Comment: i am using eclipse in mac. I unchecked 'Copy projects into workspace' but it is still not working.

Comment: @Nuraiz I have given an answer for your problem. See it below

Comment: If unchecking 'Copy projects into workspace' doesn't work, try the refresh button on right and then uncheck it.

Comment: switch the radio button either from "Select root directory" to "Select archive file" or the other way round and switch it back afterwards. THIS WORKS !

Comment: in new eclipse Mars.1 `File->Import->General->File system`

Comment: Sorry to revive an old section, but is there any headlines to do exactly that from the command line? If Batch it would be nice, if not, any direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you still got problems because Eclipse doesn't want to import projects in your workspace (i.e. grays them out), even if "copy" is deselected: close eclipse, goto `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins` and delete the `org.eclipse.core.resources` folder. Now restart eclipse and try to import again.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Eclipse for Mac, you have to create a new project with the same name as the folder that contains the project, which is already in the workspace. Do nothing else (no imports), just finish the wizard, and you will find all the subfolders and files in the new project created.

It's very misleading though, I had the same problem and it got me half an hour to solve it.

Comment: It would have saved me a lot of headaches if I had found this earlier.

Comment: I am on Eclipse for Linux, and I had to right click on the folder and click refresh.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same Problem as Nuraiz but i was able to work around.

You have to select the project you want to open and uncheck the 'Copy projects into workspace'. Then switch the radio button either from "Select root directory" to "Select archive file" or the other way round and switch it back afterwards.

You can now magically select your project or maybe it is already selected.

Comment: You help me a lot! But I think it's a bug that we have to switch the radio button in order to comlete the process.

Answer (score 9):

It is already open, but your windows "Package explorer" and "Project explorer" are closed and you do not see it. Go to Tab Window then Show view and chose any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You will see the same in Project Explorer. As If you do any checkout , it will fall in Project explorer syn with your workspace.